# Initializing a std::array from a recursive template computation

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote this code for an [answer over on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38532676/388520).  I suspect it's possible to clean it up a bit, particularly the base-case specialization for `FactorialArray`, which is repetitive and contains odd bits (for instance: why double curly braces? because clang complains about un-braced subobject initializers otherwise...)

Any and all suggestions are appreciated.  Note that `Factorial` is separate from `FactorialArray` for pedagogical clarity; I realize this makes the compile-time calculation O(N<sup>2</sup>) unless the compiler is clever enough to memoize it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cinttypes>
#include <array>

using std::uint64_t;

// Helper template that computes the factorial of one integer
template<uint64_t I> struct Factorial
{ static constexpr uint64_t value = I * Factorial<I-1>::value; };

template<> struct Factorial<0> { static constexpr uint64_t value = 1; };

// FactorialArray recursively assembles the desired array as a variadic
// template argument pack from a series of invocations of Factorial
template<uint64_t I, uint64_t... Values> struct FactorialArray
  : FactorialArray<I-1, Factorial<I>::value, Values...>
{};

// and in the base case, initializes a std::array with that pack
template<uint64_t... Values> struct FactorialArray<uint64_t(-1), Values...>
  : std::array<uint64_t, sizeof...(Values)>
{
  constexpr FactorialArray()
    : std::array<uint64_t, sizeof...(Values)> ({{Values...}})
  {}
};

int main()
{
  static FactorialArray<10> f;
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < f.size(); i++)
    std::cout << i << "! = " << f[i] << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think your code is fine for the most part. I don't like the inheritance from `std::array`, seeing as you can do the same thing with a static array data member, which would make the code easier to maintain (less coupling).

If you're well-and-truly in C++14 land, I think the code is clearer if you use `constexpr` functions rather than functions-disguised-as-structs:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <array>

constexpr size_t factorial(size_t t) {
    return t == 0 ? 1 : t * factorial(t - 1);
}

template<size_t... i>
constexpr auto factorial_array(std::index_sequence<i...>) {
    return std::array<size_t, sizeof...(i)>{{factorial(i)...}};
}

template<size_t size>
constexpr auto factorial_array() {
    return factorial_array(std::make_index_sequence<size>{});
}

int main() {
  constexpr auto f = factorial_array<15>();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < f.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << i << "! = " << f[i] << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't know this was even possible.   What parts of it require C++14 and not just C++11?

Comment: `index_sequence` isn't in the standard library until C++14, and you'd need to explicitly declare return types rather than using `auto`.